# UNPIVOT in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, pivot, sql-server-2014

I have a table as below:

[image]

I need to convert this table's rows into columns

Expected output:

```
depotCode | containerYardCode | chargeCode | 20"GP  | 40"GP |YAC 20"GP|YAC 40"GP
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HQ        |CT1 KCT            | DGC        | 25.000 |25.000 | NULL    |NULL    
HQ        |HARBOUR YARD       | DGC        |21.000  |32.000 |18.000   |28.000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample data:

```
declare @t table (depotCode varchar(2), containerYardCode varchar(25), chargeCode varchar(3), cargoTypeCode varchar(10), effectiveDate datetime, rate numeric(5,3), yardActualCost numeric(5,3), includeGST bit)
insert into @t values ('HQ', 'CT1 KCT', 'DGC', '20"GP', '6/1/2015', 25, null, 0)
insert into @t values ('HQ', 'CT1 KCT', 'DGC', '40"GP', '6/1/2015', 25, null, 0)
insert into @t values ('HQ', 'HARBOUR YARD', 'DGC', '20"GP', '1/1/2017', 21, 18, 0)
insert into @t values ('HQ', 'HARBOUR YARD', 'DGC', '40"GP', '1/1/2017', 32, 28, 0)
```

I think you need to join 2 pivot queries together, like this:

```
SELECT sq1.depotCode, sq1.containerYardCode, sq1.chargeCode, [20"GP], [40"GP], [YAC 20"GP], [YAC 40"GP]
FROM
(
    SELECT depotCode, containerYardCode, chargeCode, [20"GP], [40"GP]
    FROM (SELECT depotCode, containerYardCode, chargeCode, cargoTypeCode, rate FROM @t)t
    PIVOT (sum(rate) for cargoTypeCode in ([20"GP], [40"GP]))p
)sq1
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT depotCode, containerYardCode, chargeCode, [20"GP] as [YAC 20"GP], [40"GP] as [YAC 40"GP]
    FROM (SELECT depotCode, containerYardCode, chargeCode, cargoTypeCode, yardActualCost FROM @t)t
    PIVOT (sum(yardActualCost) for cargoTypeCode in ([20"GP], [40"GP]))p
)sq2 ON sq1.depotCode = sq2.depotCode AND sq1.containerYardCode = sq2.containerYardCode AND sq1.chargeCode = sq2.chargeCode
```

And here's the output:

```
depotCode   containerYardCode   chargeCode  20"GP   40"GP   YAC 20"GP   YAC 40"GP
HQ          CT1 KCT             DGC         25.000  25.000  NULL        NULL
HQ          HARBOUR YARD        DGC         21.000  32.000  18.000      28.000
```

The key is in the FROM clauses of the subqueries - only include the columns necessary for each individual pivot, and then join the subqueries on the common columns (e.g. depotCode, containerYardCode, chargeCode).

Comment: Hi Max, thanks for the reply. may I know, how can the column `cargotypecode` can be dynamic, means if there is many `cargotypecode` will be inserted like `20"HQ','40"HQ`. can it be done without hardcode ?

Comment: You'll need to use dynamic SQL for that. Basically, build your query as a string and use sp_executesql to run it. PIVOT requires you hardcode those values, but you can query a list of distinct values and use them to build your query. It's kind of a fun exercise.